# Not including old JS in Firebase hosting causes service worker white screen

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, firebase-hosting, create-react-app

The build process of create-react-app (`yarn run build`) deletes the old static JS file before building anew. When deployed to Firebase Hosting, the old JS files are not included and are no longer served.

However after visiting the old version the Service Worker (built by sw-precache and sw-precache-webpack-plugin, included by default in CRA) has cached the old HTML, which includes the old JS file, which is no longer served, so I get a white screen and an error in the console, which is only fixed by clearing cache and reloading.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that my Cache-Control headers were too short, meaning that my JS file wasn't being cached for long enough, causing the browser to re-request it upon a reload and not find it until the Service Worker updates.

**Resolution:** have long Cache-Control headers

Comment: Ah! I have been wondering why this was happening. Do you remember what value you set and was this across all your file types? Or did you have a specific one for the js files?

Comment: @James have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-headers, set a Cache-Control of 31536000 (1 year)

Comment: oh, that's a lot higher than I have been setting mine. Did you do that for just .js files? 

Thanks for the link. That's how I've been controlling my cache, seems like I just did quite have the correct configuration yet.

Comment: I have updated the cache control and I can see that on the response headers, but the expires is still very short. I'm starting to think I have a slightly different issue, albeit with the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this slightly differently to Marks [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594991/1185264).

Within your firebase.json file you need to make sure the Service Worker **and** the index.html file aren't cached. For me it was the index.html being cached which was the main issue.

Webpack changes the chunks name with each build and removes the previous version from /build. Therefore when they don't get uploaded and your browser looks at the cached index.html file it causes the white screen and the error.

I ended up with the following in my firebase.json file. Hope that helps

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/service-worker.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-store"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/index.html",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-store"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```